# Deleting [ ] Rows in Array Struct MATLAB

Tags: matlab, structure, rows

I  have a 24x1 (track) structure containing numerous 1x#  (data) structs. They are similar to this:

```
Lat    Lon   Date
------------------
40.1, -53.5  736257

33.8, -52.3  736255

41.6, -50.1  736400

39.5, -48.4  735600
```

I wanted to delete specific dates from the structure in order to filter some data. In which I did:

```
for i= 1:length(track)
   for j= 1:length(track(i).data)
    strdate = track(i).data(j).Date;

    if strdate == 736257 

        track(i).data(j).Date = [];
        track(i).data(j).Lat = [];
        track(i).data(j).Lon = [];


    end
  end
end
```

This leaves me with various rows of [ ] throughout the structure and not what I was actually wanting. I want to completely remove these lines (knowing obviously the size of the structure will change). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @excaza I added an example of the struct. Trying to keep it simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to completely remove all the invalid j coordinates in data cell, you can try the following approach:

```
for i= 1:length(track)
    %Initialize a mask which marks the indices which should be kept with true
   indsToKeep = false(length(track(i).data),1);

   for j= 1:length(track(i).data)
       strdate = track(i).data(j).Date;
       %if strdate is relevant, mark the corresponding coordinate as true
       if strdate ~= 736257 
           indsToKeep (j) = true;
       end
   end
   %deletes all the irelevant structs from track(i).data, using indsToKeep 
   track(i).data = track(i).data(indsToKeep);
end
```

However, if you just want to erase the 'Date', 'Lon', and 'Lat' fields of the irrelevant coordinates, you can use rmfield function.

Code example:

```
%generates a strct with two fields, and prints it
strct.f1=1;
strct.f2=2;
strct
%remove the first field and prints it
strct2 = rmfield(strct,'f1');
strct2
```

Results:

```
strct = 

    f2: 2
    f1: 1


strct2 = 

    f2: 2
```

And in your case:

```
track(i).data(j) = rmfield(track(i).data(j),'Date');
track(i).data(j) = rmfield(track(i).data(j),'Lat');
track(i).data(j) = rmfield(track(i).data(j),'Lon');
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think you mixed up the true and false                 `indsToKeep = true(length(track(i).data),1);` 
more code
`if strdate ~= 736257 
           indsToKeep (j) = true;
 end`

Comment: It should work as well.You can either set the initial array as true values and than change it into false values when required, or try the other way around.

Comment: Only reason I brought it up is because the resulting structure is actually all the dates I want to exclude.